# API.AI - web page based examples

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es

Do we have examples of API.AI based web pages that respond to user queries, and learn and better the responses. I searched the web, but did not find any. Probably missing something basic.

Answer (score 0):

OK- if you are just looking for how to deploy an API.ai chatbot to a custom web based application (rather than Facebook messenger for example) I'd recommend checking out this question:
[how to connect my chatbot user interface to APIAI serverhost via python sdk or javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43253299/how-to-connect-my-chatbot-user-interface-to-apiai-serverhost-via-python-sdk-or-j/43434921#43434921)

I spelled out most of the details and linked to a full working example. That should get you started.

Comment: The second case, where the chat bot is integrated into a web app and one can chat from browser.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply wish to embed a chatbot you have already built using API.AI into a webpage, it is quite straightforward. You need to publish the bot from your API.AI workspace, copy the embed code and paste it into your HTML. This will not be a white label chatbot you can customize, it will simply be within an iFrame. It also has some limitations with regards to formatting (e.g. you cannot have clickable hyperlinks) and other rich text.

You can check out this article on my blog if you want more details.

http://miningbusinessdata.com/embedding-api-ai-chatbot-into-your-wordpress-site/

You can also see some examples of some (simplistic) chatbots I have embedded into my own WordPress blog

http://miningbusinessdata.com/botfolio/

**Update 04/28/17:**

I have figured out how to write some custom code to do this. You can check my article about this:
https://miningbusinessdata.com/adding-faq-chatbot-to-your-wordpress-site-using-api-ai/

Answer (score 0):

```
Insert your access Token and enjoy! 
   <html>
    <head>
        <title>BOT </title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var accessToken = "yourAccessToken";
            var baseUrl = "https://api.api.ai/v1/";
            var synth ;  
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#input").keypress(function(event) {
                    if (event.which == 13) {
                        event.preventDefault();
                        send();
                    }
                });
                $("#rec").click(function(event) {
                    switchRecognition();
                });
            });
            var recognition;
            function startRecognition() {
                recognition = new webkitSpeechRecognition();
                recognition.onstart = function(event) {
                    updateRec();
                };
                recognition.onresult = function(event) {
                    var text = "";
                    for (var i = event.resultIndex; i < event.results.length; ++i) {
                        text += event.results[i][0].transcript;
                    }
                    setInput(text);
                    stopRecognition();
                };
                recognition.onend = function() {
                    stopRecognition();
                };
                recognition.lang = "en-US";
                recognition.start();
            }

            function stopRecognition() {
                if (recognition) {
                    recognition.stop();
                    recognition = null;
                }
                updateRec();
            }
            function switchRecognition() {
                if (recognition) {
                    stopRecognition();
                } else {
                    startRecognition();
                }
            }
            function setInput(text) {
                $("#input").val(text);
                send();
            }
            function updateRec() {
                $("#rec").text(recognition ? "Stop" : "Speak");
            }
            function send() {
                var text = $("#input").val();
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: baseUrl + "query?v=20150910",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    headers: {
                        "Authorization": "Bearer " + accessToken
                    },
                    data: JSON.stringify({ query: text, lang: "en", sessionId: "somerandomthing" }),
                    success: function(data) {
                        setResponse(JSON.stringify(data, undefined, 2));
                    },
                    error: function() {
                        setResponse("Errore di comunicazione con il server.");
                    }
                });
                setResponse("Caricamento...");
            }
            function setResponse(val) {
            //$("#response").text(val);
            var obj = JSON.parse(val);
            var response = obj.result.fulfillment.messages[0].speech;//testo a capo  //obj.result.fulfillment.speech;
            if (response != null)
                $("#response").text(response);
                else 
                $("#response").text(val);


            }
        </script>
        <style type="text/css">
            body { width: 500px; margin: 0 auto; text-align: center; margin-top: 20px; }
            div {  position: absolute; }
            input { width: 400px; }
            button { width: 50px; }
            textarea { width: 100%; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <input id="input" type="text"> <button id="rec">Speak</button>
            <br>Response<br> <textarea id="response" cols="40" rows="20"></textarea>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```